# Differentiate the summation over an index of a rank 3 tensor.

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, tensors

$X^{i,j,\lambda}$ is a rank 3 tensor, $W^{i,j}$ is a matrix.

Is it possible to analytically solve the following?

$\frac{d}{dX}\left|| W -  \sum_\lambda X \right||^{2}$

I know with matrices we can rewrite the sum over an index using a vector of ones, but dont think this applies here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to evaluate $\frac{d}{dX^{ij\lambda}}(\sum_\mu X^{kl\mu}-W^{kl})(\sum_\nu X^{kl\nu}-W^{kl})$, you'll need to use $\frac{d}{dX^{ij\lambda}}X^{kl\mu}=\delta_i^k\delta_j^l\delta_\lambda^\mu$ or some variant thereof due to anti/symmetries of $X$ if any.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\A{{\cal A}}\def\B{{\cal B}}\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the all-ones vector $u$
and the matrix variable $M$ as
$$\eqalign{
M &= \LR{X\cdot u-W} \qiq dM = dX\cdot u \\
}$$
Let's also use $\,\A\star\B,$ $\,\A\cdot\B,$ $\,\A:\B,$ $\,\A\therefore\B\;$ to denote the various products
$$\eqalign{
\C &= \A\star\B
 &\qiq \C_{ijkpqr} &= A_{ijk}B_{pqr} \\
\C &= \A\cdot\B
 &\qiq \;\;\C_{ijpq} &= \sum_{k=1}^K A_{ijk}B_{kpq} \\
\C &= \A:\B
 &\qiq \quad\,\C_{ip} &= \sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{k=1}^K A_{ijk}B_{jkp} \\
\C &= \A\therefore\B
 &\qiq \qquad\C &= \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{k=1}^K A_{ijk}B_{ijk} \\
}$$
Write the objective function using the above notation,
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \bigl\|M\bigr\|_F^2 \\
 &= M:M \\
\\
d\phi &= 2M:dM \\
 &= 2M:\LR{dX\cdot u}  \\
 &= \LR{2M\star u}\,\therefore\, dX \\
\\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= 2M\star u \\
\\
}$$